# Cardinality of the image of a finite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

If X is a finite set, and f : X → Y is a function, then f(X) is a
finite set with |f(X)| ≤ |X|.

*My attempt at the proof:*

From the definition of the image of a function: ∀y ∈ f(X) ∃x ∈ X s.t. y = f(x). Thus, we can select a subset of X that has a bijection to f(X) by choosing exactly one element in X for every y ∈ Y s.t y = f(x). Let this subset be X'. Since it is a subset of X, it is finite and |X'| <= |X|.

Define function g: X' → f(X) as g(x') = f(x'). Then by construction g is both injective and surjective. Thus, g is a bijection from X' to f(X), meaning that |X'| = |f(X)| and f(X) is finite. So we have |f(X)| = |X'| <= |X|.

*Notes:*

The part about a subset of a finite set being finite is from the previous part of the same problem. The part where I construct the set X' does not seem rigorous enough. This is from Tao's Analysis I book, and I could not find suitable axioms to prove that such a set exists (or can be constructed), even though it is intuitive.

I would appreciate any help with my proof.

Comment: The Axiom of Choice is exactly what's needed

Comment: Because you are dealing with finite sets you could prove it by induction on the cardinality of set $X$. Then AC is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Axiom of Choice for finite sets, Russel and Whitehead proved that for every finite set there exist a choice function for the set, that's exactly what you need. The proof follows by induction:

-The empty function is the only choice function for empty set

-Now given $n\in\omega$ let's suppose that there exist a choice function for every finite set of $n$ elements. Now let's take a set $A$ with $n+1$ elements, so $A=B\cup\{a\}$ where $B$ is a set of $n$ elements and $a\not\in B$, so by the hypothesis there exist some function $f$ that is a choice function for $B$. $f'=f\cup\{a,a'\}$ is a choice function for $A$, where $a'\in a$.

So your construction of the set is perfectly fine